Bar chart label to show percent percent of bin's count versus total rows
Using Spotfire analyst 14.0.1 HF 004
There's 207481 rows of data total.
I have a bar chart showing the number of row counts with a custom binning. I.e.
x-axis = BinBySpecificLimits([peak_symmetry],1,2,3,10)
Currently the labels on each bar are the Counts of the bar. I.e.
value axis = Count([peak_symmetry])
The chart looks like this, currently.

I'd prefer the labels on the bars to show the percent of the total count that falls within the bin. I.e. If there are 207,481 rows of all data, and 127,660 rows where peak_symmetry is between 0-1, then the label should show 0.61 or 61%and 1-2 should show 55154/207481 = 0.26 or 26%
I have tried to use %of total but this was clearly wrong.

And then I tried customizing the function to ...
Count([peak_symmetry]) THEN [Value] / Count([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.X]))
...but it came up with the same values.
Is there a function to calculate what percent of the total number of rows the count in the bin is?
